# Why my dismiss() method not able close Customize Alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dismiss

I am developing a android app where I have created Customize alert dialog. I declare Globally alert dialog and  and  AlertDialog.builder as follow. Now I am calling three method f1(), f2(),f3(), in button click.

```
btn_my_order.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      f1();
      f2(); 
      f3();
  return false;
        }
    });
```

I Declared orderDialog and   builde globally  as follow :-

```
 private AlertDialog orderDialog = null;
 AlertDialog.Builder builder;
```

My f1() block is as follow :-

```
       F1{

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainScreen.this);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    /**
     * by the help of inflater my ordre is showing in list view
     */
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    orderDialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_order_list,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.order_list_root));
    orderList = (ListView) orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.order_list);

    ibOrderDelete = (ImageButton)orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.deleteOrder);
    tvPrice = (TextView) orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.order_list_total);
    tvTaxes = (TextView) orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.order_list_taxes);
    tvTotal = (TextView) orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.order_list_grand_total);
    Button bclose = (Button) orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.close);
    Button bPlaceOrder = (Button) orderDialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.my_order_placeorder);

    bclose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) { 
            orderDialog.dismiss();   
            System.out.println(" click on close button");


        }      
    });

    /**      
     * click of place order to kitchen    
     */   
    bPlaceOrder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Place order click");

            palceMyOrdertoServer();
            new SendOrderFromTable().execute();
            System.out.println("place order to server is called");
            String msg = "Your Order is Successfully placed to Kitcken";
            Message msgObject = new Message();
            msgObject.what = 1;             
            msgObject.obj = msg;
            addMenuItemHandler.sendMessage(msgObject);
        orderDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });}
```

My f2() is for some  Cursor  work  with data base

```
    F2{
   // many stuff to be here populate data from cursor and bind it with adapter
    // no any issue in this mehod
     }
```

Now finally I am calling f3()

```
      F3{
        builder.setView(orderDialogLayout);
    orderDialog = builder.create();
    orderDialog.show();
       }
```

Now i am going to explain all my problem f1() method is for initialization f2() is for populate data and f3() to show customize alert dialog . Why my

```
       orderDialog.dismiss();
```

is not working for me.Even though i am able to see my logcat with message

```
        "Click on close button"
```

That means execution is going on dismiss() method then why customize alert dialog didn't close at click. Thanks in advance to all

Comment: it is because you are dismissing it in f1 while initializing orderDialog in f3

Comment: @Raghunandan..That means if i called dismiss in f3() then it work?..and thanks for your quick response..

Comment: give it a try and let me know

Comment: @Raghunandan.. I tried your suggestion but still getting same issue.. Please help me take me out of tis issue

Comment: sure orderDialog is shown/?

Comment: yess....i can send u you screen shot

Comment: @Raghunandan..are you there? What is issue in my code..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40098/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-blue-green)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `final` in your `orderDialog` private variable.

Comment: @muntssir....Thanks for your  response..If i declare as final. then how could i initialize orderDialog  in f3() block...?

Comment: Try reconsidering your approach. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423028/java-local-variable-visibility-in-anonymous-inner-classes-why-is-final-keywo) is why it should be final

Comment: I must say your coding style is not very pleasant to read. Reconsidering it may be a good idea.

Comment: @muntasir..,,,..I am checking your link ..Thanks...May i ask a question , What is not pleasant in my coding style?

Comment: @muntasir..and if it is issue of final,,, then why i am getting   "Click on close button" in my logcat? THat means click event perfomed very well....

Comment: @BlueGreen implement `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener` override `onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)` and log something there see if it logs anything. `alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(ActivityName.this)`

Comment: @Raghunandan...Thanks..I want to say one thing.your are one of help-full guy in this portal.Let me check your suggestion.

Comment: @Raghunandan... when i am implementing this showing null pointer exception

Comment: orderDialog.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(" my dismiss listener is called");
   }
  });